# Преобразовать строку (дата) в long

Tags: android, строки, дата, android-edittext, datepicker

Имею в одном edittext дату. Получаю ее в виде строки вида "12.07.2017".

```
dateFromString = dateFrom.getText().toString();
```

Далее мне нужно установить ограничение на ввод минимальной даты.
То есть в другом edittext в диалоге выбора даты делаю

```
chooseDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Long.parseLong(dateFromString));
```

Но!

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.07.2017"
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:443)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте стандартные возможности языка `Java`. А распарсить у вас не может, потомучто в строке содержаться точки, если их убрать, то сможете получить `long`, но не рекомендую Вам так работать с датами и временем.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try
{
      convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFromString);
      chooseDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(convertedDate.getTime(‌​));
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Теперь всё работает: chooseDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(convertedDate.getTime());

Comment: @Evgeny GooDi chooseDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(convertedDate.getTime())